# Can´t implement firebase-ui-auth

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being
>   requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but
>   resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies
>   tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies

I´ve got this error and can´t solve it. I tried everything I found, but nothing worked. Do you have an idea.
I wanted to implement **implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.alexa.oneline"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }


}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //LifeData
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"

    //room db
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"

    //Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.1'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Update the google services and then check: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'`

Comment: updated it but it diden´t help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**firebase-core** [latest version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-core/16.0.4) is: `16.0.4` but the [Firestore version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-firestore/17.1.1) seems to be all good.

So, change your dependencies to:

```
//Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.1'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'
```

Then add;

```
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Right after:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In your `build.gradle`.